# npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: npm, nexus, ca

So this issue is happening when I try to run NPM PUBLISH to the NPM-Private Repo in Nexus.

I was able to create a PEM file in the following order to be able to run NPM INSTALL from behind the firewall successfully.

PROXY
Issuing SUBCA1
ROOT CA

There are two possible subca's that issue certs in the environment that this is running in and the cert for the internal private repo is issued by SUBCA2.

I've tried creating a PEM with all of the certs but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do this or if I have the order incorrect, or even if there is a way to set a separate PEM for NPM to use to publish and install with?

Proxy
Nexus Server
SUBCA2
SUBCA1
ROOT CA

Pretty new to NPM and I'm I don't typically have to create PEM files from multiple certs...most of my experience is using Maven to pull artifacts and publish to our internal repos and working with a cacerts store, so any help/thoughts would be appreciated.

I've tried to set the CAFILE in the npm user and global config to the 2 different PEM files I've created as well as just trying to point it straight to my IBM JDK CACERTS file hoping that would get the job done but I'm just stuck at this point.

NPM Install works without a hitch at this point so I think its just my PEM file that is screwed up.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.